# Как пишется сочетание "личностно()ориентированная педагогика"?

Tags: орфография, сложные-прилагательные

Вроде бы совсем недавно все согласились, что  это терминологическое сочетание  надо писать **через дефис**, то есть пусть оно будет **словом, а не словосочетанием.**

Теперь в словарях опять **раздельное написание наречия перед прилагательным**.

А в Нацкорпусе есть и **другие примеры с дефисным написанием**, в том числе в научной литературе, например: *личностно-смысловой, личностно-психический, личностно-эмоциональный.*

Так как же пишутся такие слова (словосочетания) с элементом ***личностно***, **эта тема разбирается в правилах?**

**Примеры**

Якиманская И. С. Технология **личностно-ориентированного** образования. [Г. А. Цукерман. Развитие учебного сообщества (2004) // «Вопросы психологии», 2004.02.10]

Это будет координата **личностно-жизненного** аспекта культуры. [А. Л. Доброхотов. А. Ф. Лосев – философ культуры (2009)]

Карпова Н.Л. Основы **личностно-направленной** логопсихотерапии: Уч. пособие, 2-е изд. [Н. Л. Карпова. Идеи и опыт В. Н. Мясищева в практике семейной групповой логопсихотерапии (2003) // «Вопросы психологии», 2003.10.21]

Но «круг познания» вновь и вновь заявляет о себе чувственным, **личностно-смысловым…** [П. А. Мясоед. Психология в аспекте типов научной рациональности (2004) // «Вопросы психологии», 2004.12.14]

Comment: Зачем же вы сравниваете личностно-смысловой и личностно ориентированный. Разные вещи!

Comment: Может быть, и разные, но я ведь ничего не сравниваю, а всего лишь спрашиваю. Существуют ли обе формы и как они различаются (то есть почему  это  разные вещи).  Хорошо бы еще в словаре найти такие слова или хотя бы их разбор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, действительно, полный разнобой. "Грамота"и словарь Лопатина дают раздельное написание, а во многих педагогических изданиях мы видим дефисное написание. Вот интересная статья в  Альманахе современной науки и образования, № 12 (31) 2009, часть 2 157 СЛОЖНЫЕ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫЕ И СОЧЕТАНИЯ СЛОВ СО ВТОРЫМ КОМПОНЕНТОМ ОРИЕНТИРОВАННЫЙ В СОВРЕМЕННОМ РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ. Автор -  Каунова Екатерина Викторовна, Волгоградский государственный педагогический университет:

В «Словообразовательном словаре русского языка» А. Н. Тихонова производное слово ориентированный дано с пометой «прил., прич.», образовано от глагола ориентироваться [Тихонов, 2008, с. 708]: таким образом, в контекстном окружении оно может выступать в предложении в роли прилагательного или причастия. В «Толковом словаре русского языка» С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой слово ориентированный мотивируется глаголом ориентировать и имеет следующее лексическое значение с пометой «книжное»: «осведомленный, знающий, разбирающийся в деле» [Ожегов, 1999, с. 460]. Однако в нашем случае слово ориентированный имеет и другое значение: «взять (брать) направление на кого-что-н.», мотивируется глаголом ориентироваться [Там же]. Например, личностно ориентированное образование – «образование ориентировано (т.е. направлено) на личность» или предметно ориентированные технологии – «технологии ориентированы (т.е. направлены) на предмет».

В современной лингвистике до сих пор не разработана теория разграничения сложного слова и сочетания «наречие + причастие/прилагательное», и поэтому в практике письма отмечается разнобой в оформлении подобных слов.

В словарях также наблюдается разнобой. В «Русском орфографическом словаре» (2007 г.) выявлено 16 сочетаний, вторым компонентом которых является слово ориентированный, а в словаре-справочнике «Слитно или раздельно?» (1998 г.) – 23, из них 7 оформлены через дефис, остальные 16 – раздельно.

В соответствии с рекомендациями «Правил» (1956 г.) возможны только два способа написания сложных прилагательных со вторым **причастным** компонентом — **слитное или раздельное** (см. § 80 «Правил»). **К дефисному же написанию стремятся образования со вторым компонентом причастием, их первый компонент представляет собой грамматически оформленное прилагательное.** В нашем случае трудность представляют те сочетания слов, где предстоит решить следующие вопросы:

1) чем является первый компонент – наречием или прилагательным;

2) чем является второй компонент ориентированный – прилагательным или страдательным причастием;

3) являются ли подобные слова терминами или не являются.

Б. З. Букчина и Л. П. Калакуцкая также считают, что *«Сложность орфографического оформления прилагательных, относящихся к данной группе, состоит в отсутствии формальных показателей, разграничивающих в их первой части прилагательные и образования наречного типа»* [Букчина, 1974, с. 49].

В заключение следует отметить, что большая часть исследуемых сложных прилагательных в словарях все же пишется раздельно, а в практике печати преобладает в основном дефисное оформление эти же лексических единиц.

Автор советует:

-Нам представляется, что **подобные образования правильнее рассматривать как «наречие / прилагательное и причастие ориентированный» и писать раздельно, например: личностно ориентированный, коммуникативно ориентированный, строго ориентированный и др.**

Так что, видимо, разнобой продолжится, если даже в научной среде разные мнения. Хотя сейчас для школ, например, обязательно написание по Лопатину, а у него раздельно: наречие + причастие (образование или обучение ориентировано на личность - личностно ориентированное), а не сложное слово-сращение личностный и ориентированный (знающий личность).Акценты разные.

Comment: http://scjournal.ru/articles/issn_1993-5552_2009_12-2_62.pdf

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, я приму Ваш ответ, но дополню его своими соображениями  на эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

**«В современной лингвистике до сих пор не разработана теория разграничения сложного слова и сочетания «наречие + причастие/прилагательное»?**

**Да она никогда не будет разработана**, если у разработчиков этой темы полностью отсутствует логика.

Яснее ясного, что   «личностно-ориентированная» **является термином, который определяет вид педагогики** (другие виды: возрастная, лечебная, классическая,  также педагогика сотрудничества, креативная и т.д.).

**Термин должен быть словом, а не словосочетанием, он определяется как единое целое,** например: « вечнозелёное растение – это растение, чья листва сохраняется в течение всего года».

**Слово же может писаться или слитно, или через дефис**. Выбор дефисного написания объясняется фонетическими причинами:  слитно написанный вариант будет сложно восприниматься на письме.

**А вот «личностно ориентированное образование» надо писать раздельно,** это действительно свободное словосочетание, а не термин-классификатор. **Поэтому должны быть нормированными обе записи.**

Точно так же всё происходит с другими парами вида «термин – свободное словосочетание», например **малонаселенный и мало населенный**, только обычно термин пишется слитно, а в нашем случае – через дефис.

Современная же лингвистика эту задачу решить не может, потому что **подходит к решению  безо всякой начальной мысли** –  формально и наугад.

Comment: Ну, это Вы уж слишком, ну, подскажите им, может, поймут.

Comment: Я же не медиум, а другим способом подсказать ничего нельзя.