# Сколько Н в слове "компьютеризирова (Н, НН) о-виртуальный"?

Tags: нн, н

Столкнулась в одной рукописи с термином "компьютеризировано-виртуальная среда". У автора одна буква Н. Хотела проверить в словарях, но не могу найти.

Слово "компьютеризированный" пишется с НН. Тогда почему этот термин с одной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, это термин: ***компьютеризировано-виртуальная среда.***

Если написать ***компьютеризированно-виртуальная среда***,  то это будет сложное прилагательное ***компьютеризированная виртуальная*** среда, что, возможно, не соответствует значению термина.

В данном случае первая часть используется в значении **наречного** сочетания "по отношению к компьютеризации, компьютерной технике". Форма записи соответствует **краткому**  причастию с одной ***Н***: виртуальная среда **компьютеризована**.

**Примечание.**

1. Возможны другие варианты записи: ***компьютерно-виртуальная/компьютеро-виртуальная** среда*, и они лучше воспринимаются в записи, да и сточки зрения **словообразования** тоже. Нельзя исключить того, что это более **подходящий термин.** Но выбор нужной формы можно сделать только **по содержанию** текста.
2. Похожая  ситуация с термином ***"личностно-ориентированный"***. Такое слово указано в словаре методических **терминов**, но в общем значении это сочетание пишется так: ***личностно ориентированный*** (по словарю РАН). Термин пишется через дефис, а обычное сочетание раздельно, то есть существуют **две** записи.

Таким образом, написание слова может иметь **варианты** в зависимости от его **значения** (термин или сложное прилагательное). Специалист, который пишет статью, должен знать терминологию по заданной теме и использовать **нужный** ему вариант. Это можно уточнить у автора.

**Материалы по теме:**

**[Что такое виртуальная машина?](https://timeweb.com/ru/community/articles/chto-takoe-virtualnaya-mashina)**
Виртуальная машина (ВМ, VM) – это виртуальная среда, работающая как настоящий компьютер, но внутри другого компьютера. Если выражаться проще, то это приложение, которое имитирует компьютер с полноценной операционной системой и аппаратным обеспечением.

[Как пишется сочетание "личностно()ориентированная педагогика"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443794/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/443826#443826)

[Грамота.ру](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=all&l=1)

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ. Всё поняла.